# "Другой, кроме..." — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Другой персонаж, кроме тех, которые нам уже известны..." — мне эта фраза кажется неуклюжей. А вообще сочетание "другой, кроме..." имеет ли право на существование?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фразы "другой, кроме" вполне себе возможны и довольно частотны. Ваш отрывок действительно выглядит неуклюже, но не из-за того, что используется подобная конструкция, а из-за того, что к слову в ед. ч. относится местоимение во множественном. Ср. *Другие персонажи, кроме тех, которые нам уже известны...*. Поэтому фразу, действительно,  стоит переделать